# return $scope from Angular Controller to access it in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I make a method that returns $scope from an Angular Controller so that I can access $scope in an html page?

This is the code of my controller btw

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

        $http.get('/books2').success(function(response) {
            $scope.books2=response;
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: That's the most anti-angularJS question ever!
The $scope is the base, please start from here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02.

Comment: whats your use case for this?

Comment: @Karim I think you are just trying to display book2 on the page. is this correct?  If so you need to learn about angular a bit more.  namely automatic data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access controller scope from out side the controller you can use
var scope = angular.element("[ng-controller='myController']").scope()

but this is totally not recommended